# How get index when break was called, in a for-range loop?

Tags: go

Code:

```golang
arr := []string{"A", "B", "C", "D"}

i := 0

for i, s := range arr {
    fmt.Println(i, s)
    if s == "C" {
        break
    }
}

fmt.Println(i)
```

Output:

```
0 A
1 B
2 C
0
```

Expected:

```
0 A
1 B
2 C
2
```

I was expecting that I can access "i" outside for-range, since it was initialized beforehand. May be there is something related to scope of the variable that I am missing, if so how to achieve what I am expecting?

*Note: I am new to golang.

Comment: They have different scope, so the `i` in the for-loop is a new variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are redeclaring your `i` variable inside the loop. See [Declarations and scope](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Declarations_and_scope), specifically [Short Variable Declarations](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations).

You can access the variables both inside and outside of the loop, as long as you declare them both in the outer scope (https://go.dev/play/p/Q3OJ0mUZJH-)

```
arr := []string{"A", "B", "C", "D"}

i := 0
s := ""

for i, s = range arr {
    fmt.Println(i, s)
    if s == "C" {
        break
    }
}

fmt.Println(i)
```

Comment: Also [this](https://go.dev/ref/spec#For_range).

Comment: I was not aware that ":=" in the for statement re-declared the variable.